# Need help installing an extention in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is this an extension I want to install:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zhengrenzhe.nyan-cat#qna

According to the steps I need to  `shift + command + p` and search for Nyan Cat: refresh status bar.
But when I do that it says: command 'extension.NyanCatRefresh' not found

I am pretty noob tho so if anyone can help me I would be very happy :)

Tried installing and uninstalling it, does not work.

Also tried [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqBMa.png)

Screenshots:
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEZQT.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7pBN.png)

UPDATE

I mailed the creator and he said the following:
"thanks for your email, this extension has long time not update, so it maybe encounter some bugs in latest vscode version. 
I will fix it in recent days"

So I will wait for now and then I'll come back here and tell you if it works/

Comment: Can you please share screenshot?

Comment: Sure, just added screenshots

Comment: Same thing with me. Why you need this extension? look like you have latest version of VS code which does not support this extension. they have to upgrade this extension.

Comment: I just like this extention :) So they HAVE to upgrade their extention? there is nothing else I can do?

Comment: I thought so... If you like try contributing to their source code . https://github.com/zhengrenzhe/vscode-Nyan-Cat. No updates from more than one and half year